# Can't not use jimp with webpack

Tags: javascript, image-processing, webpack

I'm using [jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) with webpack,but the page alway show this:

> Uncaught Error: define cannot be used indirect

Also I have try to add `module.noParses` config in my webpack.config.js like below:

> noParse: [/jimp/]

but it will console other error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Just so confused,no really where the problem is,maybe the jimp is not incompatible with webpack?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this myself, looks like using the imports loader helps:

```
import 'imports?require=>false!path/to/jimp.js'
```

You can also do it via webpack.config.js in `module.loaders`:

```
{
    test: /jimp/,
    loader: 'imports?require=>false',
}
```

If you have other loaders (e.g. babel) you might also need to exclude jimp from that config as well.