# facing 36 errors after require("obj2gltf") with webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, dependencies, node-modules

I have a 3D- application running perfectly with webpack. I want to add further functionality with the package `obj2gltf`. Installing with `npm install --save-dev obj2glftf`. Loading with `const obj2glft = require("obj2gltf")`.
After building the application I see 36 errors, all like:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/pngjs/lib/filter-parse-async.js 3:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'path/node_modules/pngjs/lib

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
...
```

and:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cesium/index.cjs 13:17-16:2
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I don't understand why. Should I add something to the `webpack.config.js`?

Minimal working example:
index.js:

```
const obj2gltf = require("obj2gltf");

const container = document.getElementById("app");
container.innerHTML='test'
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>3DView, Kanton Basel-Landschaft</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js:

```
"use strict";

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    app: './index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
    sourcePrefix:''
  },
  mode: 'development'
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testobjerror",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/webpack serve --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "obj2gltf": "^3.1.6",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

What i tried:
Installing the npm-package globally (with -g), did not change anything.
Reudcing the whole application to this minimal working example. --> problem seems to be the `obj2gltf`-package
I added a loader like in this answer [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524512/cant-not-use-jimp-with-webpack):

```
{
    test: /obj2gltf/,
    loader: 'imports?require=>false',
}
```

I also tried a solution with a plugin ([text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699311/require-a-jquery-plugin-with-webpack)), but i don't understand the plugins and didn't get it work.