# cannot require package 'obj2gltf' with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, require

original Question: [facing 36 errors after require("obj2gltf") with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77110879/facing-36-errors-after-requireobj2gltf-with-webpack)

I try to load the module 'obj2gltf' with webpack. The configuration works when i delete the row `const obj2gltf = require("obj2gltf");` in the index.js. With this row, there appear three errormessages:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js 1:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/philipp/Code/3D-Viewer/testObjError/node_modules/graceful-fs'
 @ ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js 5:11-33
 @ ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js 5:5-20
 @ ./node_modules/obj2gltf/lib/obj2gltf.js 3:16-35
 @ ./node_modules/obj2gltf/index.js 2:0-42
 @ ./src/index.js 1:17-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonfile/index.js 5:8-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/philipp/Code/3D-Viewer/testObjError/node_modules/jsonfile'
 @ ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/jsonfile.js 3:17-36
 @ ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/index.js 4:17-38
 @ ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js 10:5-22
 @ ./node_modules/obj2gltf/lib/obj2gltf.js 3:16-35
 @ ./node_modules/obj2gltf/index.js 2:0-42
 @ ./src/index.js 1:17-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/obj2gltf/lib/readLines.js 4:17-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'readline' in '/home/philipp/Code/3D-Viewer/testObjError/node_modules/obj2gltf/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/obj2gltf/lib/loadObj.js 9:18-40
 @ ./node_modules/obj2gltf/lib/obj2gltf.js 6:16-36
 @ ./node_modules/obj2gltf/index.js 2:0-42
 @ ./src/index.js 1:17-36
```

There is also one warning caused of the same module:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/cesium/index.cjs 13:17-16:2
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/obj2gltf/lib/obj2gltf.js 2:15-32
 @ ./node_modules/obj2gltf/index.js 2:0-42
 @ ./src/index.js 1:17-36
```

It seems that the module 'obj2gltf' loads other modules in a manner that causes this problems. Has this problem to be fixed in the module itself or is there a way to fix this in my configuration?
Is there a workaround?
Do anybody have any suggestions?

webpack.config.js:

```
 "use strict";

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
    sourcePrefix:''
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      url: false,
      zlib: false,
      https: false,
      http: false,
      assert: false,
      util: false,
      buffer: false, 
      path: false,
      stream: false,
      constants: false
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        inject:true,
        filename: 'index.html'
    }),
  ],
  mode: 'development'
};
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>3DView, Kanton Basel-Landschaft</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
const obj2gltf = require("obj2gltf");
const container = document.getElementById("app");
container.innerHTML='test';
```

package.json:

```
  "name": "testobjerror",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/webpack serve --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "obj2gltf": "^3.1.6",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

file tree:

```
|_dist
|_node_modules
|_src
  |_index.html
  |_index.js
|_package.json
|_package-lock.json
|_webpack.config.json
```

Loading the package differently (`import * as obj2gltf from "obj2gltf";`) did not work. Supressing the warning worked, but the errors remain.